# Getting "this email address is already registered" when I try to update the About Me section

Tags: support, users

I was trying to update the "About Me" section in my profile, but I got this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

So...I did the email verification thing, etc., but I'm still getting the same error. What do I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think thats exactly what I did.. sigh!

Comment: Are you sure? You read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts), then you went to the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) page, picked "I need to merge user profiles", and submitted your request? Then you allowed 24-48 hours for a living, breathing human being to handle it? I can't actually tell whether or not you've done that, but that's what you should have done.

Comment: @CodyGray - I think the OP meant that they created a duplicate account by mistake...

Comment: I understand that, @silencedmessage. What I'm describing is the procedure to have the duplicate account merged into their main account, which should correct the problem.